# What is XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using *linq to xml*.

In this we load xml file as `XDocument.Load("filename.xml")`.

What is this `XDocument`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? For questions like these documentation is your resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case XDocument is a class which allows you to call the static method Load.
This Load method returns an instance of XDocument.

Comment: This is explaining what's Load method, instead of what's XDocument.

Comment: You have partially right, but in this case the question was : What is a XDocument in the following exemple :  XDocument.Load("filename.xml").  I think my answer fit the question.

Answer (score 11):

XDocument is a .NET class which represents an XML Document in memory but with specific support for Linq. It is part of the System.Xml.Linq namespace. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Comment: Thanks alot its reall useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

`XDocument` is a class representing an XML document, providing LINQ-friendly behaviors and approaches.

It's `System.Xml.XmlDocument` equivalent for the LINQ era.

Comment: Great to know that :D Good luck in your XML and LINQ adventures!